# How to get attribute in XML

Tags: java, xml

Thanks for previous replies.

I am parsing XML file using java(SAXParser), i am not sure how to parse the attribute value(meta data) using attribute value. I given two main categoy 
`<category name="XYZ" /> <category name="ABC"/>`
'

```
            <subcategory name="" loc="C://program files" link="www.sample.com" parentnode="XYZ"/>
            <subcategory name="" loc="C://program files" link="http://" parentnode="ABC"/>`
```

In sub category i have linked the main category with parentnode attribute. my question is i want to get all the attribute which is only contains particular parent attribute. (Ex)i want all attribute which is only resides in parent attribute "ABC". is this possible to get a value.

Comment: How do you do the "parsing"? DOM, SAX, XPath, or did you roll your own?

Comment: Forgot to include that, using SAXParser

Comment: You have control over the XML you need to parse? I mean you decide yourself how it looks? Then I find it strange to use 'parentnode' attributes. `<category name="XYZ"><subcategory name="" ... /></category>` seems a much nicer way to build up the xml. And catching the event in SAX where the category has name "blah" and only then parse (or else skip) shouldn't be too hard. The SAX tutorial explains how to do that in detail. And as an afterthought: maybe you can change the XSD/XML to use nodes and values, and less attributes. Depends on your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the code below is solution for your problem?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<categories>
    <category name="ABC">
        <subcategory name="123" 
            loc="C://program files" 
            link="www.sample.com" 
            parentnode="ABC"/>
        <subcategory name="456" 
            loc="C://program files" 
            link="http://" 
            parentnode="ABC"/>
    </category>

    <category name="XYZ"> 
        <subcategory name="123" 
            loc="C://program files" 
            link="www.sample.com" 
            parentnode="XYZ"/>
        <subcategory name="456" 
            loc="C://program files" 
            link="http://abc.com" 
            parentnode="XYZ"/>
    </category>
</categories>
```

JAVA

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Question6855476 {
private static final String CFG_XML_PATH = "D:\\sample\\path\\question6855476.xml";
private static final String searchArg = "ABC";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List locList = getLocsByCategoryName(searchArg);
    List linkList = getLinksByCategoryName(searchArg);

    printCollection(locList,"LOC");
    printCollection(linkList,"LINKS");

}

private static void printCollection(List locList, String string) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("### Collection: "+string+"\n");
    if(locList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("\tNo items. Collection is empty.");
    } else {
        for(Object obj: locList) {
            System.out.println("\t"+obj);
        }
    }

}

private static List getLocsByCategoryName(String catName) {
    if(null==catName||catName.length()<=0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: catName is null/blank");
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    } else {
        return getSubcatAttrValuesByAttrName("loc", catName);
    }
}

private static List getLinksByCategoryName(String catName) {
    if(null==catName||catName.length()<=0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: catName is null/blank");
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    } else {
        return getSubcatAttrValuesByAttrName("link", catName);
    }
}

private static List<Object> getSubcatAttrValuesByAttrName(String attrName, String catName) {

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    if(null==attrName||attrName.length()<=0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: attrName is null/blank");
    } else {
        try {
              File file = new File(CFG_XML_PATH);
              DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
              DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
              Document doc = db.parse(file);
              doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

              NodeList catLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("category");

              for (int i = 0; i < catLst.getLength(); i++) {

                  Node cat = catLst.item(i);

                  NamedNodeMap catAttrMap = cat.getAttributes();
                  Node catAttr = catAttrMap.getNamedItem("name");

                  if(catName.equals(catAttr.getNodeValue())){ // CLUE!!!

                      NodeList subcatLst = cat.getChildNodes();

                      for (int j = 0; j < subcatLst.getLength(); j++) {
                          Node subcat = subcatLst.item(j);
                          NamedNodeMap subcatAttrMap = subcat.getAttributes();

                          if(subcatAttrMap!=null) {
                              Node subcatAttr = subcatAttrMap.getNamedItem(attrName);
                              list.add(subcatAttr.getNodeValue());
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
        } catch (Exception e) { // FIXME
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

I've based on [this article](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html)

Comment: amazing, thanks. Can you guide me how to delete the subcategory using category name..

Comment: delete from xml file or java object?

Comment: delete from xml file, i want to delete the sub category according to the category attribute name.

Comment: @Hopbit Like I mentioned in another comment: DOM loads the entire XML which in case of the example might be peanuts but can be troublesome when the 'real life' XML is much bigger. #HariRam If you're deleting from XML, I think XSLT would be of much more use.

Comment: @Wivani Yeah, in case of big XML files/streams we should use SAXP or anybody recommend other library?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you mean you want to get all the attributes of `subcategory` elements with `parentnode` attribute value equals to "ABC"? So you want to get the attributes `(name="" loc="C://program files" link="http://" parentnode="ABC")` in the example you gave?

The basic parsing code should look like this:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
MySAXHandler handler = new MySAXHandler();
handler.setDesireParentNodeAttributeValue("ABC");
parser.parse(xmlInputStream, handler);

/* 
 *this list contains all the attributes of the subcategory element that has
 * parentnode attribute equals to "ABC"
 */
List<Attributes> whatIWant = handler.getDesireAttributes();

//do whatever you wnat with "whatIWant"

....

public class MySAXHandler extends DefaultHandler2
{
    private String desirePrentNodeAttributeValue;
    private List<Attributes> desireAttributes = new ArrayList<Attributes>();

    public void setDesireParentNodeAttributeValue(String val)
    {
        this.desirePrentNodeAttributeValue = val;
    }

    public List<Attributes> getDesireAttributes()
    {
        return desireAttributes;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri,
                         String localName,
                         String qName,
                         Attributes attributes)
    throws SAXException
    {
        if ("subcategory".equals(localName)
            && attributes
                .getValue("parentnode")
                .equals(this.desirePrentNodeAttributeValue))
        {
             desireAttributes.add(attributes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've parsed you XML you could wander through the data to find what you need, but a better approach may be to use XPath to query the XML.

There some tutorial material [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html#javaxpath)

Comment: This answer seems to cover the DOM parsing more than SAX, isn't it? And the OP seems to have the requirement to only parse certain nodes and not the entire XML. XPATH could be a solution, though I seem to remember it loads the entire document and that might not fit the requirements here.